# save git stash revision long term

Tags: git, version-control, patch, git-stash

How do I

"Save" a git stash and store it away long terms such that I can access it in the future (perhaps save it in some patch file) even after the stash itself is cleared. IE. how do I save a certain stash into a file such that I can clear the current stashes and that nothing will show up if I do git stash list and yet I will still be able to access the saved stash revision in the future if I want to

Comment: I think that the best way to do this is using a patch file. https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git

Comment: it seems to me that creating a patch file requires commits...is there a way to just create a patch file from the stash/uncommitted changes such that I don't have to commit them first

Comment: You can create patchs using `$ git diff`, so instead of use stash, you can use `$ git add .`, `$ git diff --cached --no-prefix > patch_name.patch`. And _voilà_, you will have a fresh patch. After that you can reset your files, and to apply this patch use `$ patch -p0 < patch_name.patch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked for a file, but I would use git to save the change set -- much easier to keep track of than a file.

Create a new branch

```
git checkout -b saved_stash
```

pop the stash, add and commit

```
git stash pop
git add .
git commit -m 'save stash for later'
```

When you want to use it again checkout the branch, reset the commit and add to stash again

```
git checkout saved_stash
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git stash
```

At this point you should have the same stash state you originaly saved.

(typed on the run, commands may be off slightly -- I hope only slightly)